# Grid layout manager with dynamic item

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use grid layout manager but not working good for dynamic item

What I want:

[image]

or just like

[image]

And What it shows:

[image]

Comment: Your item layout has height wrap_content?

Comment: can you add your implementation code here, by this pictures we can not understand how you are using grid layout manager

Comment: maybe you are looking for a staggered layout instead of grid layout. staggered layout can make view like this

Answer (score 0):

use StaggeredGridLayoutManager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
         StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 
         StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: i use this but want to set span dynamic for column

Comment: Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
```

> https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);